# How to find a character string not enclosed in tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Using Beautifulsoup, I want to find string not enclosed by tag and enclose it with `<p>` but I do not know how to do it.

```
<p>string</p>
<figure class="image"> <img alt="" src="sample.jpg"/> </figure>
string,string,string<br/>
<p>string,string</p>
string
<p><a href="/test" target="_blank">string</a></p>
textexttext
<p>stringstring</p>
<p><a href="tel:xxxxxxxx" target="_blank">xxxxxxxxxx</a></p>
<div>textextext</div>
<p>string,string<br/>string</p>
```

I would like to change html as above

```
<p>string</p>
<figure class="image"> <img alt="" src="sample.jpg"/> </figure>
<p>string,string,string</p><br/>       <-here
<p>string,string</p>
<p>string</p>                     <- here
<p><a href="/test" target="_blank">string</a></p>
<p>textexttext</p>               <- here
<p>stringstring</p>
<p><a href="tel:xxxxxxxx">xxxxxxxxxx</a></p>
<div>textextext</div>
<p>string,string<br/>string</p>
```

I tried the following method, but it did not work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = """<p>string</p>
    <figure class="image"> <img alt="" src="sample.jpg"/> </figure>
    <p>string,string,string</p><br/> <-here
    <p>string,string</p>
    <p>string</p> <- here
    <p><a href="/test" target="_blank">string</a></p>
    <p>textexttext</p>    <- here
    <p>stringstring</p>
    <p><a href="tel:xxxxxxxx" target="_blank">xxxxxxxxxx</a></p>
    <div>textextext</div>
    <p>string,string<br/>string</p>"""

soup = BS(html, "html.parser")

while True:
    text = soup.find(text=True)
    if not text:
        break
    if not text.parent.name in ['p', 'span', 'a', 'div']:
        text.wrap(content.new_tag("p"))
```

Comment: Do you *require* to use BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """<p>string</p>
<figure class="image"> <img alt="" src="sample.jpg"/> </figure>
string,string,string<br/>
<p>string,string</p>
string
<p><a href="/test" target="_blank">string</a></p>
textexttext
<p>stringstring</p>
<p><a href="tel:xxxxxxxx" target="_blank">xxxxxxxxxx</a></p>
<div>textextext</div>
<p>string,string<br/>string</p>"""

soup = bs(html, "html.parser")

for text in soup.find_all(text=True):
    if not text.parent.name in ['p', 'span', 'a', 'div'] and len(text.strip()):
        text.wrap(soup.new_tag("p"))

print soup
```

This will give you the following output:

```
<p>string</p>
<figure class="image"> <img alt="" src="sample.jpg"/> </figure><p>
string,string,string</p><br/>
<p>string,string</p><p>
string
</p><p><a href="/test" target="_blank">string</a></p><p>
textexttext
</p><p>stringstring</p>
<p><a href="tel:xxxxxxxx" target="_blank">xxxxxxxxxx</a></p>
<div>textextext</div>
<p>string,string<br/>string</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is alwanys at the beginning of a line you could do something like that:

```
import re
text = """<p>string</p>
<figure class="image"> <img alt="" src="sample.jpg"/> </figure>
string,string,string<br/>
<p>string,string</p>
string
<p><a href="/test" target="_blank">string</a></p>
textexttext
<p>stringstring</p>
<p><a href="tel:xxxxxxxx" target="_blank">xxxxxxxxxx</a></p>
<div>textextext</div>
<p>string,string<br/>string</p>"""
r = re.compile(r"(?<=\n)([^\n<>\\]*)")
print(r.sub('<p>\g<1></p>', text))
```